# Can I use Arduino Software and IDE for development on Freeduino Atmega 328

Tags: arduino

Can I use [Arduino Software](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/) and IDE for development on Freeduino Atmega 328?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "Freeduino" (no idea what that is) uses the Arduino bootloader and is connected via some form of UART interface to the same UART pins as the Arduino, then yes, you can.  The Arduino UNO uses the Atmel 328P chip as well, so you could use that.

The only possible issue might be with the oscillator configuration - if this Freeduino thing uses the same oscillator arrangement as the UNO then you will have no problems.

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie. I checked it's features and it says - "Comes with an Atmega328 with a preburnt Arduino bootloader". Do that mean yes?

Comment: I would say yes ;)

Comment: Yes, the Freeduino ( [a](http://www.freeduino.org/freeduino_open_designs.html) [b](http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?products_id=4123) ) is "100% functionally, electrically and physically compatible with Arduino hardware."